# Minimize the mean square error $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \| x_i - S(t_i)\|_2^2$ for a Bezier curve

Tags: polynomials, optimization

The problem is **2.1** from [here](http://www.math.ntnu.no/emner/TMA4215/2013h/project2/project2.pdf).
I am trying to minimize the mean error 
$$
   E(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \| x_i - S(t_i)\|_2^2
$$
Where $x_i$, lie on the curve $\gamma$ and $S(t_i)$ is a cubic Bezier curve. Eg
$$
    S(t)=(1-t)^3\mathbf{P}_0+3(1-t)^2t\mathbf{P}_1+3(1-t)t^2\mathbf{P}_2+t^3\mathbf{P}_3 \mbox{ , } t \in [0,1]
$$
I am given that

- $\mathbf{P}_0$ and $\mathbf{P}_3$ are the first and last points on the curve $x_1$ and $x_m$ pressumably.
- $\mathbf{P}_1 = \mathbf{P}_0 + \alpha_1 \mathbf{v}_0$ and 
  $\mathbf{P}_2 = \mathbf{P}_3 + \alpha_2 \mathbf{v}_3$

Where $v_0$ and $v_3$ are known.
Now my plan was differentiating $E$ with respect to $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ to obtain a set of independent equations. Minimizimg $E$ is the same as minimizing  $\| x_i - S(t_i)\|_2^2 = (x_1)^2 - S(t_i)^2$. Eg 
$$
  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}E(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)
                               = 0^2 +
  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha} S(t)^2
                               =
  2S(t) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha} S(t)
$$
Where $\alpha$ could be either $\alpha_1$ or $\alpha_2$.By inserting my conditions for $\mathbf{P}_1,\cdots,\mathbf{P}_4$ into the formula for $S(t)$ and solving the linear system I get rubbish. I get that $\alpha_1$ can be choosen freely, and that $S(t)=0 \forall t$ which is crazy since it should be approximating a curve. My question is, how do I find $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$?

The derivation, and solving the linear set of equations was done using maple so I doubt the error lies there.

Just for the sake of completion my explicit expression for turns out to be 
$$
   S(t) = (1-t)^3 x_1 + 3(1-t)^2 t (x_1 + \alpha_1 \mathbf{v}_0) + 
            3(1-t)t^2(x_m + \alpha_2 \mathbf{v_3}) + t^3 x_m
$$
And 
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha_1} E(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) 
                                 = 
                   6 \cdot S(t) \cdot (1-t)^2 t \mathbf{v_0} 
                                 = 0 \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha_2} E(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) 
                                 = 
                   6 \cdot S(t) \cdot (1-t)t^2 \mathbf{v_3} 
                                 = 0 \\
\end{align*}
Where I write $t = t_i$ for shorthands sake. 
Which both windles down into $S(t)$... So the linear independent system is not independent. [Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyOja.png) I used to check my derivations.

Any help finding $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ would be much appreciated =)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late, but here are a couple of comments:

(1) $\mathbf{v}_0$ and $\mathbf{v}_3$ are not unknowns; they are the initial and final derivative vectors of the given curve $\gamma$.

(2) Your objective function $E(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ is wrong. It's not true that $\| x_i - S(t_i)\|_2^2 = (x_i)^2 - S(t_i)^2$

Except for that, your reasoning seems OK.